# Nikon Transfer & Memory Cards

Tags: nikon, memory-card, file-transfer

I recently began using Nikon Transfer to download images from my memory card. For a trip, I purchased 2 Lexar SD cards & also brought along an older ScanDisk.  At the end of a day of shooting, I downloaded pictures from the Scandisk (used in one small Canon) and from the Lexar used in my Nikon D3100.  I had the program delete the photos from the cards after download.  When I went to use the cards, in two different cameras, they would not retain the image. Fortunately, I still had an unused Lexar and used that.  I was able to download pictures from that card and re-use BUT I didn't have Nikon Transfer delete the pictures from the card.  As soon as I did have Transfer delete the pictures from the card, the card became unusable.
Anyone have experience with this problem & can offer some suggestions? I feel that this should be fixable with some clicking around but don't know where to begin.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have not ever used Nikon Transfer before, so I don't know if I can address the issue directly, but it is a good practice to format your cards in the camera after you have cleared them off using the computer.

This is where you format a card with the d3100.

[image]